# How can I embed an Instagram video feed based on the hashtag?

Tags: video, embed, feed, instagram, hashtag

I've been looking through Instagrams API trying to figure out exactly how I would show JUST the videos from a certain #hashtag specified in the API call..

If you take a look at the Instagram home page for their blog: http://blog.instagram.com/
This feed for "#WHPmyfavoriteplace" is much like what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use the `/tags/tag-name/media/recent` endpoint to retrieve media by tag. There does not appear to be a way to specify what type of media to retrieve yet. You will need to run through your result set and look for media where type => 'video' and ignore where type => 'image'.

Comment: I was looking at this exact query earlier today. Thank you for clearing it up for me :)